# install fusefs gem using bundle in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to RoR and I am trying to install an application that we have at work and i have to run bundle install to install some gems that are required for the application to work. One of them is fusefs v 0.7.0 but when I run bundle install it fails when it gets to try to install fusefs stating

Error: Error installing fusefs:
       Error: failed to build gem native extension

```
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
  checking for main() in -lfuse_ino64... no
  checking for main() in -lfuse... no
```

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details.

So at this point I have spend several days trying to get ruby, rails, passenger, mysql and apache to play nice on 10.8 and I am stuck at this last little piece.

Any help will be appreciated it.

Update ********
Well I just found my answer. The fusefs is a build specifically for linux.

Answer (score 2):

FUSE is originally a Linux feature. There have been similar interfaces written for OS X ([osxfuse](http://osxfuse.github.com/) and [fuse4x](http://fuse4x.github.com/)) and various BSDs. You might want to see if one of them is compatible. It looks like there is a [fusefs-osx Gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/fusefs-osx); I'm not sure whether that uses osxfuse, fuse4x, or the older MacFUSE which is no longer maintained, but you could try replacing the fusefs dependency with fusefs-osx and see if that works.